# why my thread in android run more than once when i open my application more than one?

Tags: android, eclipse

i have this code in android .my code is for reply to multicast msg.it work normaly when i open this application for first.but i use the button back for android and i open for second,this application work more than one and reply more than one reponse .

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView info, infoip, msg;
     String message = "";
     ServerSocket serverSocket;
     String s;

      String ipserver;

      String replyip;
       int i;
       int j;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
      infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
      msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
      i=0;
      j=1;
      infoip.setText(getIpAddress());
      WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      WifiInfo infor =manager.getConnectionInfo();
      String addr=infor.getMacAddress();
      this.s=addr;


    Thread t = new Thread (new SocketServerThread());
    if(!t.isAlive()){
    t.start();
    }


     }

     @Override
     protected void onRestart(){


     }


     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
     i=1;
     j=0;


      if (serverSocket != null) {
       try {
        serverSocket.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     }

     private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

      static final int SocketServerPORT = 7000;
      int count = 0;

      @Override
      public void run() {
       try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          info.setText("\n+I'm waiting here: "
            + serverSocket.getLocalPort()+"\n \n");
         }
        });

        while (true) {
            MulticastSocket sock = new MulticastSocket(12345);

            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1");
            sock.joinGroup(addr);

            DatagramPacket packet;
            byte [] buffer= new byte[256];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            sock.receive(packet);
            String Message =  new String (packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength());

            replyip =packet.getSocketAddress().toString().substring(0, 13);
            message+=Message+replyip;

            sock.close();

         MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
           msg.setText(message);
          }
         });



        SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(replyip, count);

       if(i==0 )
       {
        socketServerReplyThread.run();

       }

       if(j==0){

           socketServerReplyThread.run();

       }


        }
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

     }

     private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {



      String ips;

      SocketServerReplyThread(String ip, int c) {


       ips=ip;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {




       try {



                    Socket s=new Socket(ips.toString(),12345);
                    DataOutputStream dos =new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    String a = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                    dos.writeUTF(a);
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                    s.close();














        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          msg.setText(message);
         }
        });

       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";

       }

       MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
         msg.setText(message);
        }
       });
      }

     }

     private String getIpAddress() {
      String ip = "";
      try {
       Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
         .getNetworkInterfaces();
       while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
          .nextElement();
        Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
          .getInetAddresses();
        while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
         InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();



         if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {

          ip += "SiteLocalAddress: " 
            + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";



         }

        }

       }

      } catch (SocketException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
      }

      return ip;
     }
}
```

Comment: Then probably your activity gets killed by the system once you leave it. You can verify that by implementing `onDestroy()` and logging there. I guess your phone/tables has little RAM?

Comment: Limited resources is a possibility for a left activity being rapidly destroyed (it's entirely permissible behavior), but not handling orientation changes may be a more likely explanation.  Note also that onDestroy() isn't guaranteed to be called.  Examining the log in general (without filters) may be more informative.

Comment: i use the galaxy ace GTI 5830 i to run this run this application

Answer (score 0):

When you press the back button your Application is still in-memory  (verify with "adb shell ps"). When you start it again your onCreate gets called.   Now you have two instances of SocketServerThread consuming the incoming connections.

Android destroys and recreates the Activity for lots of reasons you might not expect, for example when you rotate the screen.   So you have to be careful about keeping data in an Activity.

You should move your networking code out of the Activity and into its own class.   Use a singleton or factory pattern to make sure there is only one SocketServerThread.

Comment: what do you mean with "singleton".how i can use a singleton?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is while(true) line in your thread's run method. As many times Activity is created, new Thread is being created and its being executed in infinite loop. If you launch app "n" times, n threads will be created.

1. Note that socketServerReplyThread.run(); call does not starts a Thread. Its a simple method call.
2. isAlive check in below code is use-less as a new Thread object has created above it.

   Thread t = new Thread(new SocketServerThread());
           if (!t.isAlive()) {
               t.start();
           }
3. To fix this issue, you can have a flag to check whether activity is destroyed or not. and run loop till activity is destroyed. This will make sure that Thread will have no task once activity is destroyed.

   while(isDestroyed){
   // do task
   }

   protected void onDestroy() {
       super.onDestroy();
   isDestroyed = true;
   }

I have edited your code below to make sure that multiple threads are not created.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView info, infoip, msg;
     String message = "";
     ServerSocket serverSocket;
     String s;

      String ipserver;

      String replyip;
       int i;
       int j;

private boolean mIsDestroyed = false;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
      info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
      infoip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.infoip);
      msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
      i=0;
      j=1;
      infoip.setText(getIpAddress());
      WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      WifiInfo infor =manager.getConnectionInfo();
      String addr=infor.getMacAddress();
      this.s=addr;


    Thread t = new Thread (new SocketServerThread());
    if(!t.isAlive()){
    t.start();
    }


     }

     @Override
     protected void onRestart(){


     }


     @Override
     protected void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
mIsDestroyed = true;
     i=1;
     j=0;


      if (serverSocket != null) {
       try {
        serverSocket.close();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
     }

     private class SocketServerThread extends Thread {

      static final int SocketServerPORT = 7000;
      int count = 0;

      @Override
      public void run() {
       try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);
        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          info.setText("\n+I'm waiting here: "
            + serverSocket.getLocalPort()+"\n \n");
         }
        });

        while (mIsDestroyed == false) {
            MulticastSocket sock = new MulticastSocket(12345);

            InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("224.0.0.1");
            sock.joinGroup(addr);

            DatagramPacket packet;
            byte [] buffer= new byte[256];
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            sock.receive(packet);
            String Message =  new String (packet.getData(),0,packet.getLength());

            replyip =packet.getSocketAddress().toString().substring(0, 13);
            message+=Message+replyip;

            sock.close();

         MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {
           msg.setText(message);
          }
         });



        SocketServerReplyThread socketServerReplyThread = new SocketServerReplyThread(replyip, count);

       if(i==0 )
       {
        socketServerReplyThread.run();

       }

       if(j==0){

           socketServerReplyThread.run();

       }


        }
       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }

     }

     private class SocketServerReplyThread extends Thread {



      String ips;

      SocketServerReplyThread(String ip, int c) {


       ips=ip;
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {




       try {



                    Socket s=new Socket(ips.toString(),12345);
                    DataOutputStream dos =new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
                    TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                    String a = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
                    dos.writeUTF(a);
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();
                    s.close();














        MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

         @Override
         public void run() {
          msg.setText(message);
         }
        });

       } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        message += "Something wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";

       }

       MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
         msg.setText(message);
        }
       });
      }

     }

     private String getIpAddress() {
      String ip = "";
      try {
       Enumeration<NetworkInterface> enumNetworkInterfaces = NetworkInterface
         .getNetworkInterfaces();
       while (enumNetworkInterfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = enumNetworkInterfaces
          .nextElement();
        Enumeration<InetAddress> enumInetAddress = networkInterface
          .getInetAddresses();
        while (enumInetAddress.hasMoreElements()) {
         InetAddress inetAddress = enumInetAddress.nextElement();



         if (inetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()) {

          ip += "SiteLocalAddress: " 
            + inetAddress.getHostAddress() + "\n";



         }

        }

       }

      } catch (SocketException e) {
       // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
       ip += "Something Wrong! " + e.toString() + "\n";
      }

      return ip;
     }
}
```

Comment: but can you get me a final code whith your change ?

Comment: 10x again .my code running very well.but i want to my code stay running in the background when i press the back button

Answer (score 0):

Try with Singleton pattern as mentioned below:

```
    public class MySingleton implements Runnable {
        private static MySingleton sInstance;
        private boolean mIsThreadStarted = false;

        // Use this method to access object of this class. Only single object of
        // this class will be created and thread will be started only once.
        public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance() {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = new MySingleton();
            }
            return sInstance;
        }

        private MySingleton() {
            // Remove below call if you want start it later.
            startThread();
        }
  // Call this method whenever thread is to be started.  
        public void startThread() {
            if (mIsThreadStarted) {
                // Already started.
                return;
            }
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
            mIsThreadStarted = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Your logic here, which should be running continuously.
            while (true) {
                // This loop will be running continuously till the app is running.
                // You will need to Implement Callback/Listener mechanism to pass
                // events to Activity.
            }
        }
    }
```